# Don't enter record if already exists, access linked table to sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, triggers, linked-tables

I have an application which has access front end and sql back-end.

It used to be Access=>Access but it got migrated.

The problem occurs in a linked table where entering an already existing record used to just display a user friendly (this record already exists) message.

But now a non-user friendly sql message appears.(Violation of PK, etc)

I was going to solve it using an instead of trigger (haven't tried it yet)

Is there another way to do it? pref from Access itself.

Comment: using access no, but could do using triggers

Comment: You could possibly use error-handling code (if this sql-error can be caught). A lot of people do this, relying on the PK violation, rather than checking for an existing record.

Comment: Yes, sounds better indeed

Comment: "Can you first check whether the row exists" -- I have to think you can do this, using the typical VBA solution, `BeforeUpdate()` ... or maybe it's not that function, as this is a record addition, but should be straightforward in any case.

Comment: @Smandoli
Sadly because access is thinking that i am editing the table directly - not in a list or form, there is no VBA actions nor macros..just validation Rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using code, but you can also do this using just SQL.  Assuming `column1` is the primary key, here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( column1, column2 )
SELECT column1,
  column2
FROM MyOtherTable AS a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
  FROM MyTable AS b
  WHERE b.column1 = a.column1 );
```

In this example, I use `SELECT 1` since I am just checking if a row was returned and don't care what was actually returned.  Your code can then display a user-friendly error message if zero rows were inserted.